# Given a list of events with timestamps, how do I use R to calculate the average rate at which such event is happening?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a CSV file with a list of posts from an online discussion forum. I have the timestamp for each post in this format: YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.

I want to calculate how often a new post is submitted, as in "X posts per second". I think what I need is just the mean, median and sd for the rate of posting (posts per second). I just loaded the CSV:

```
d <- read.csv("posts.csv")
colnames(d) <- c("post.id", "timestamp")
```

Comment: I would start to do a `hist(diff(d$timestamp))` and see what it looks like. I'll bet the distribution will be (at least) bimodal, and in that case the mean posts/seconds will be kind of meaningless

Answer (score 3):

The average number of posts per second is just 1/interval from last posting, so make a vector of diff(times) and then take mean(1/as.numeric(diff(times))).

```
> posts <- data.frame(ids = paste(letters[sample(1:26, 100, replace=TRUE)], 
                  sample(1:100) ),  time=Sys.time() +cumsum(abs(rnorm(100))*100) )

    > mean( 1/as.numeric(diff(posts$time)) )
[1] 0.03545346
```

Edit: I thought that by using cumsum I would get the time series ordered, but that was not the case, so it's amended to take abs(rnorm(100) ).

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think our answers (I contributed the one above) are not exactly equivalent -- but they may be different in an interesting way  Consider for example a situation where posts are made exactly once a minute.  Your solution will give diff(post$time) as a vector of (1/60,1/60,1/60,...), mean=median=1/60, sd 0. My solution will give (1,0,0,0,...1,0,0,0,...) -- mean of 1/60, median of 0,sd of sqrt((1-1/60)^2/60).  I think I like your solution better. They should converge as the number of hits per sample period increases (I think).

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question. How do I use my data in your code? Do I just replace sample(1:26,100, replace=TRUE) for my d$timestamp?

Comment: If timestamps are sample(1:26,100, replace=TRUE) then they are not ordered, and so the first step would be to sort them. You are going to have some problems at that point with your example, since 1/0 == Inf. So I think my solution is not good for situations where ties for timestamps are possible and methods (like Ben Bolker's) that use table or cut are better.

Comment: I see. From a cursory analysis of my dataset I can see that there are multiple posts that are posted at the exact same second, so there are ties for timestamps. I will then look into more detail at Ben's method.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
tt <- table(cut(as.POSIXlt(d$timestamp),"1 sec"))
c(mean(tt),median(tt),sd(tt))
```

You didn't provide a reproducible example so I'm not 100% sure this works, but something like that ... also don't know how well it will scale to giant data sets.

More detail (with example):

```
set.seed(1001)
n <- 1e5
nt <- 1e5
z <- seq(as.POSIXct("2010-09-01"),length=nt,by="1 sec")
length(z)
z2 <- sample(z,size=n,replace=TRUE)
tt <- table(cut(z2,"1 sec"))
c(mean(tt),median(tt),sd(tt))
```

This tiny example suggests that the cut() command might be slow.
Play with the 'nt' (number of seconds in the time interval from beginning to end) and 'n' (number of samples) parameters to get a sense of how long your problem will take.

Comment: my data set is about 5 million posts. What do you mean by a reproducible example? Here are some possible values

Comment: 813941001,"2010-07-29 01:23:45"

Comment: 81314567,"2010-08-02 15:13:01"

Answer (score 0):

i dont know your programming language, but if you could convert the timestamp to milliseconds, just subtract the lowest from the highest timestamp, then divide by the number of posts (rows in the posts.csv) then divide by 1000 (milliseconds) and your left with posts per second. Or if you can get the timestamp in seconds, it is the same except don't divide by 1000.

Comment: The programming language is R.

Comment: ok, i have no clue what that is. sorry, cant help with specifics.

Comment: why is this getting downvoted? It's a valid generic solution, no need to downvote just because he did not insert R code.

Comment: nice of you to say nico, but i'm not interested in reputation or whatever counts is on this site, just thought i could help:)

Comment: well, the idea of the votes is for the community to define useful or unuseful answers. Reputation is a fun side-effect but is not really the main point and I agree with you that one can live without. This answer is probably not resolving the exact problem of the question, but can be useful for someone else interested in a similar (but not the same exact) problem. That's why I was saying that it should not have been downvoted.